# How to get nationality from Flickr Photo Search Query?

Tags: tags, flickr

I am extracting some metadata from FLICKR PHOTO SEARCH. I have now constructed a query, which pretty much does what I want: https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=.....&text=yes&bbox=....&has_geo=1&extras=geo%2C+description&per_page=500&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_sig=...

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there any argument that provides me information on the nationality of the Flickr user?
2. How to modify the arguments in order to include "Tags" to the query?

thanks,
A.

Answer (score 0):

Per [flickr.photos.search](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html), add `&tags=` to your URL query string to search by tag.

Given a photo, you can use [flickr.photos.getInfo](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getInfo.html) to determine the user (the `owner` attribute), and from there you can use [flickr.people.getInfo](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.people.getInfo.html) to get the user's location.  That's not the same thing as nationality, of course, but you may find that info sufficient.